# How to get the modified date of file in Unix (Including Year)?

Tags: unix

I am looking for a command to get the modified date of file in Unix including the *year* field without using `stat` because we are using SunOS 5.10.

Currently when I am using

```
ls -lrt A.sh
```

we get following details:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 dev   dev       593 Jan  1 02:18 A.sh
```

How can I get the year?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the stat command? In any case, I seem to recall you get (from ls) just the date and time if it's in the last six or so months, otherwise you get date and year.

Comment: STAT command doesn't work in SUNOS

Comment: I suggest post be migrated to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ where it's more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat hackish way:

```
truss -t lstat64 -v lstat64 /bin/ls A.sh 2>&1 |
    nawk '/mt =/ {printf("%s %2s %s %s %s\n",$3,$4,$5,$6,$7);}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a *programming* Q&A site, I would simply implement a small C program which extracts the information using the `stat` call.

It gives you a `struct stat` structure which contains `time_t` values for access, modification and status change times.

You can then use `localtime` to turn that into a `struct tm` structure and extract the relevant fields for output (from memory, `tm_year + 1900`, `tm_mon + 1` and `tm_mday` plus the time ones as well if you need them).

Answer (score 1):

`ls` has the `--time-style` option:

> ```
> --time-style=STYLE
>        with -l, show times using style STYLE: full-iso, long-iso, iso, locale, or +FORMAT; FORMAT is  inter‐
>        preted like in 'date'; if FORMAT is FORMAT1<newline>FORMAT2, then FORMAT1 applies to non-recent files
>        and FORMAT2 to recent files; if STYLE is prefixed with 'posix-', STYLE takes effect only outside  the
>        POSIX locale
> ```

which contains preloaded formats such as `long-iso`

```
ls -lrt --time-style=long-iso A.sh
```

> ```
> -rw-r--r--   1 dev   dev       593 2014-01-02 02:18 A.sh
> ```

or you can define your own based on the formats from `date`

```
ls -lrt --time-style="+%Y-%m-%d %a %T" A.sh
```

> ```
> -rw-r--r--   1 dev   dev       593 2014-01-02 Tue 02:18:00 A.sh
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%d %b %Y %H:%M ".$_, localtime((lstat)[9]) for @ARGV' a.sh
```

Comment: I think that using Perl is a good way to go.  If you want the modification time of the file, you should use `stat` rather than `lstat`, but otherwise, this (now) looks plausible (works for me on Mac OS X 10.9.1 with Perl 5.18.1, but looks like it should be OK on Solaris too).